# Reflections on C++ Variadic Templated Versions of std::min() and std::max()

Tags: c++, max, minimum, variadic-templates

I need reflections on my implementations of the C++11 variadic versions of `std::min`, `std::max`. Here are my two alternatives for `std::min`, where `std::max` is implemented analogously by just replacing `std::min` with `std::max`:

```
/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a. */
template <LessThanComparable T> const T & multi_type_min (const T & a) { return a; } // template termination
/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a and \p args. */
template <class T, class ... R >
//requires SameType <T , Args >...
T multi_type_min(const T & a, const R &... b)
{
    return std::min(a, multi_type_min(b...));
}

/*! Minimum of \p a. */
template <LessThanComparable T> const T & common_type_min(const T & a) { return a; } // template termination
/*! Minimum of \p a and \p args. */
template <class T, class ... R, class C = typename boost::common_type<T, R...>::type >
C common_type_min(const T & a, const R &... b)
{
    return std::min(static_cast<C>(a), static_cast<C>(common_type_min(b...)));
}
```

The *key question* is if we need `common_type_min` at all? Note that this allows min() to be called with one arguments. Could this cause confusions or problems?

Comment: Can't you recurse until you get 2 parameters?  There's no requirement to stop specifically at 1 parameter.

Comment: I know how do just that. I just wondered if it is better to allow `min` and `max` to take one parameter aswell for the sake of algorithm *generality* on container wrappers such as `std::tuple`.

Comment: I would tend to say that the min of a single value doesn't make sense, yet the min of a 1-element tuple does make sense.  Maybe it would be better to overload `min()` for container types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just write it such that it recurses until you stop at two parameters?

Here's a (untested) snippet:

```
/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a and \p args. */
template <class T, class U >
//requires SameType <T , U >...
T multi_type_min(const T & a, const U & b)
{
    return std::min(a, b);
}

/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a and \p args. */
template <class T, class U, class ... R >
//requires SameType <T , U, Args >...
T multi_type_min(const T & a, const U & b, const R &... c)
{
    return std::min(a, multi_type_min(b, c...));
}
```

I'm guessing the `common_type_min` variant is necessary when there are multiple common types.  Consider comparing `short` and `long` values.  Because of type promotion, the `short` will be converted to `long` for comparison.  However, some application constraint or invariant might let you know that both values can be represented by a `short`.  In this case, you may want to have `common_type_min<short>(a,b)`.

Comment: Be aware of that this version of `multi_type_min` is *right* associative. Shouldn't we prefer left instead?

Comment: @Nordlöw: seems to me like an arbitrary decision.  Why should all comparisons be performed in the type of the left operand?  Shouldn't `std::min(1, 1.0)` return a double?  If so, shouldn't `multi_type_min(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0)` also return a double?